# Javascript in an HTML file for CDOSYS CreateMHTMLBody Not Working

Tags: javascript, html-email

I would like to send a personalized email using CreateMHTMLBody. However, the javascript within the HTML file used as a template does not execute and extract the personalisation from the query string.

Here is the simple test file I'm using as the email template:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello
      <script>
        Name=location.search.split("=");
        document.write(" "+Name[1]);
      </script>
    </h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

I get the "Hello" but nothing for "Name[1]".

Here is the pertinent part of the Classic ASP script I'm using to send the HTML file:

```
  With myMail
    .Subject = "HTML Email Test"
    .From = "Support@mydomain.org"
    .Bcc = Request.Form("Email")
    .CreateMHTMLBody("http://localhost/messages/test.html?Name="+Request.Form("FirstName"))
    .Send
  End With
```

I know the CreateMHTMLBody is working as I do get an email with the "Hello", just not the Name. It could be that the CreateMHTMLBody is ignoring the query string in the supplied URL, but then I believe I should see "undefined" where the javascript was trying to modify the output.

Anyone have any idea why the javascript is not being executed?

Comment: you haven't defined Name as an array (or as a variable!) in your script..

Comment: Possible, but not probable. As the "var" declaration only affects the scope of the variable. Without "var", global. With "var", local. With this small example script It doesn't make any difference.

Comment: The string method .split() returns an array. Javascript intrinsically defines "Name" as an array.
When the email template is called directly in the browser the script works as expected. It doesn't work when embedded into the body of an email with the CreateMHTMLBody method.

Comment: OK. Added the declarative "var" to the "Name" variable; no difference.